# Прыжок и движения в пространстве - Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда я прыгаю без нажатия клавиш: вперед назад, влево, вправо, то куб плавно и самое главное быстро падает обратно на землю, все в порядке, гравитация работает, но когда я начинаю двигать кубик в воздухе, то есть в прыжке нажимая клавиши вперед, назад, вправо, влево, то он начинает падать намного медленнее, примерно у -= 0,02 секунды, хотя без нажатия где-то у -= 1 в секунду.

Как исправить чтобы он падал так же быстро как без нажатий клавиш, и без костылей?

Код:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class InputCar : MonoBehaviour
 {
  public KeyCode right;
  public KeyCode left;
  public KeyCode forward;
  public KeyCode down;
  public bool is_way = false;
  public Rigidbody player;
  public bool moveRight =true;
  public bool moveLeft = true;
  public float speed = 25f;
  float speedFor = 5f;
  public float jumpSpeed = 25.0f;
  public float gravity = 20.0f;
  public bool isPlayer = true;

  public Vector3 posPlayer;
  public Vector3 positionPlayer;

 void Start()
 {
     player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
 }

 void Update()
 {
    Debug.Log(player.transform.position.y);

    if (isPlayer == false)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Fade());
    }

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isPlayer == true)//Move Player
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(right) && Input.GetKey(forward))
        {
            player.velocity = ((Vector3.right) * (speedFor));
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(left) && Input.GetKey(forward))
        {
            player.velocity = ((Vector3.left) * (speedFor));
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(left) && Input.GetKey(down))
        {
            player.velocity = (Vector3.left * (speedFor));
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(right) && Input.GetKey(down))
        {
            player.velocity = (Vector3.right  * (speedFor));
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(forward))
        {
            player.velocity = (-Vector3.right * (speed));
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(down))
        {
            player.velocity = (Vector3.right  * (speed));
        }


        if (moveRight == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(right))
            {
                player.velocity = (Vector3.forward) * (speed / 5);
                //transform.Translate((Vector3.forward) * Time.deltaTime * (speedFor));
            }
        }

        if (moveLeft == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(left))
            {
                player.velocity = (-(Vector3.forward) * (speed / 5));
                //transform.Translate(-(Vector3.forward) * Time.deltaTime * (speedFor));
            }
        }



        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && is_way)
        {
            Debug.Log("JUMP");
            player.AddForce((Vector3.up) * jumpSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
            is_way = false;
        }
    }
}
IEnumerator Fade()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("_Scene_0");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))] // обязательные компоненты указываются

public class Car : MonoBehaviour {

    public event System.Action<bool> ControlChanged;

    // isPlayer не отображает значение переменной
    // это не просто переменная, которая тупо перепроверяется каждый update, а свойство с событием
    public bool ControlEnable {
        get => _control;
        set {
            if (_control != value) {
                _control = value;
                ControlChanged?.Invoke(_control);
            }
        }
    }

    // это переменные для внутренней кухни класса, не должны быть public
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _speed = new Vector2(25f, 5); // _speed и _speedFor ужасные названия и почему это 2 переменные
    [SerializeField] private float _jumpPower = 25.0f;
    private Rigidbody _body;
    private bool _control = true;
    // is_way... DO YOU KNOW THE WAY?
    // не отображает значение переменной
    private bool _onGround = false;

    // не меняется, в чем отличие от Input.GetKey(right) ?
    // почему используется одновременно раздельно и затем вместе, что перекрывает предыдущий код... бред
    //public bool moveRight = true; 
    //public bool moveLeft = true; // тоже самое
    //public float gravity = 20.0f; // не используется
    //public Vector3 posPlayer; // не используется
    //public Vector3 positionPlayer; // в чем разница с posPlayer?


    public void SetMovementVector (Vector2 vector) {
        if (_control) {
            vector *= _speed;
            // меняем только x и z, оставляя y как есть
            _body.velocity = new Vector3(vector.x, _body.velocity.y, vector.y);
        }
    }

    public void Jump () {
        if (_control && _onGround) {
            _body.AddForce(Vector3.up*_jumpPower, ForceMode.Impulse);
            _onGround = false;
        }
    }

    private void Awake () {
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
}
```

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Car))]

public class CarPlaerControler : MonoBehaviour {
    // вообще можно изспользовать Input.GetAxis и настраивать клавиши в меню Inputs, переменные... странно
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _forward;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _down;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _right;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _left;
    private Car _car;

    private void Awake () {
        _car = GetComponent<Car>();
        // подписываемся на событие
        _car.ControlChanged += ControlChanged;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate () {
        float AxisX = 0;
        if (Input.GetKey(_right))
            AxisX += 1;
        if (Input.GetKey(_left))
            AxisX += -1;
        float AxisY = 0;
        if (Input.GetKey(_forward))
            AxisY += 1;
        if (Input.GetKey(_down))
            AxisY += -1;
        _car.SetMovementVector(new Vector2(AxisX, AxisY));

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            _car.Jump();
    }

    // реакция на событие потери контроля
    private void ControlChanged (bool enable) {
        if (enable == false)
            StartCoroutine(Fade());
    }

    private IEnumerator Fade () {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("_Scene_0");
    }
}
```

Для врагов пишется свой `CarControler`.

Comment: Contol, Contoler, ContolChanged? Походу у вас залипает буква r... :)

Comment: @МаксимФисман, у неё после выходных трудные понедельники. `Reload` без остановки.