# Как менять силу прыжка в зависимости от продолжительности нажатия клавиши?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать управляемый прыжок в зависимости от продолжительности нажатия клавиши.

У меня есть только реализация обычного прыжка:

```
  {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
      if (onGround) {
      br.AddForce(jumpImpulse * jumpHeight);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: чего заминусовали то? это конечно не образцово-показательный вопрос, но и не настолько плохой чтобы совсем уж ему шансов не давать. Будьте добрее - дайте шанс парню

Comment: Я в юнити не шарю но рискну предположить возьми за силу константу, на событие keyPressed ставь timestamp, на keyDown currentTime, отнимаешь от второго timestamp, и умножь

Comment: @Yaroslav, всё что в `unity3d` не редкость, сможете смело умножить на 10 и тогда примерно узнаете как часто я вижу подобные сообщения. 50% вопросов на stackoverflow начинаются с того, что кто-то что-то нашел в интернете и у кого-то чего то не получилось. Давайте тогда SO вообще закроем. Смысл  модерации вопросов в том, насколько вопрос может быть полезен сообществу и насколько он соответствует правилам. Вы не конкретному Саргису помогаете если пишете ответ - а всему коммьюнити. `Unity` коммьюнити в частности. Не хотите ответ писать - ну так вас никто не заставляет. Но закрывать вопрос зачем?

Comment: @Саргис, не знаю то это или нет, но посмотрите на это https://youtu.be/7KiK0Aqtmzc?t=703, это https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/2jnukp/holding_longer_for_a_longer_jump/  и это https://stackoverflow.com/a/57045912/4558866  я не спец в юнити конечно, но если совсем не разберетесь - можете мне маякнуть потом - напишу полноценный ответ, если никто из участников по unity не определится с целесообразностью ответа.

Comment: @Yaroslav, ну так пишите ответы качественнее чтобы помогало. Не просто кодом откупайтесь, а объясняйте что вы делали, зачем, почему именно так, что Вами двигало в этот момент и что можно почитать в добавок к этой теме. Вы что Ванга что-ли чтобы знать поможет ему это или нет?

Comment: @МихаилРебров, молодец, попал пальцем прямо в... [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1235894/%d0%9f%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b6%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-unity3d/1235933#1235933) как выглядят мой обычные ответы, людям, которые что-то написали сами и хотят разобраться. Если на стеке много, тех для кото программирование это не цель, а преграда, которую не хочется преодолевать, это не повод превращать его в мусорный полигон.

Comment: @Yaroslav, ..это был пример изобилия комментариев и объяснений?.. не могу сказать что это плохой ответ. Нормальный, может даже хороший (точно мог бы сказать если бы работал с юнити)... но это не совсем то, про что я говорил. Вы молодец безусловно. Но это не отменяет того, что можно и подробнее написать. Всегда. И я это и к себе применяю. Я никого пристыдить или унизить не пытаюсь. И опять же это вообще ни разу никак не оправдывает умозаключений из ряда "преград, поводов, преодолеваний и желания разбираться". **откуда Вы это знаете?**, **почему Вы так в этом уверены?**

Comment: Все с чего-то начинают и всем хочется большего. Всегда. И в разработке тоже. И когда Вы только начинаете разрабатывать Вам сразу хочется делать крутые игры независимо от того, хватает ли у вас навыков и знаний на данный момент для этого. Даже для того чтобы элементарно разобраться в вопросе. Это не значит что человек не хочет разбираться в этом. Это значит лишь то, что у человека пока не хватает навыков, чтобы это сделать самостоятельно. Все были такими. И Вы я уверен - тоже.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, я знаю это потому, что я Ванга !. Я способен предвидеть, что метание бисера перед свиньями это тупое и бесполезное занятие. Всё равно, что рассказывать безграмотному, который не умеет и не хочет уметь читать о Чехове и Достоевском. И да, я тоже не пытаюсь оскорбить, но я прямолинеен и с чувством умора . И не гони на комменты, они там к каждой потенциально новой и не знакомой для начинающего штуке.

Comment: @Yaroslav то что я там выше в комменте набыдлокодил, оно хоть как-то похоже на дело, или лучше потереть от греха подальше? :)

Comment: @Yaroslav, что похоже? Где? Я ничего не спрашивал. Выше комментарий от другого пользователя. И если у него что-то не так, то лучше предлагать и аргументировать.

Comment: @aepot, совсем не похоже :) Ответ в прямой манипуляцией `rb.velocity` и таймере, но для него эта информация так-же полезна, как смартфон для неандертальца. Да Михаил, я ошибся.

Comment: @Yaroslav спасибо, выпилено.

Comment: @Yaroslav, я не просил за меня писать весь полноценный код. Я лишь спросил, каким образом можно реализовать. Потому что я например в ступоре, и не знаю как можно измерить время нажатия клавиши. В интернете я тоже нормального ответа не нашёл (в русскоязычном сообществе), а если вы хотите конкретно, то хорошо. Как измерить длину нажатия клавиши? (Если что код я писал сам, хоть он и слишком простой, без побрякушек и прочего)

Comment: Всем участникам спасибо за замечания и учту в следующий подобных вопросах

Comment: @Yaroslav, опять таки, я бы очень хотел разобраться, но мне нужно задать направление

Comment: @Yaroslav, на самом деле вопрос-то неплохой. И, думаю, полезный для общества. Просто заголовок был плохо сформулирован. Он я поставил плюсик, сменил заголовок, и вуаля - вопрос собрал еще 5 плюсов за вечер(кроме моего) - вполне себе неплохо для самого первого вопроса от новичка на SO :)

Comment: @Andrew, к чести Ярослава, он хотя бы высказал своё мнение в комментариях. Меня больше стадный инстинкт пугает. Когда я этот вопрос встретил в очереди у него голосов -3 было(и было бы больше) и он уже готовился к праотцам отправиться (в очередь на закрытие). Не особо радует что приходится "бучу" подымать в комментариях, чтобы люди своей головой начинали думать. Радует, что после минимального привлечения внимания адекватность восторжествовала. А то периодически вера в сообщество пропадает. Спасибо за ответ кстати (плюсик я уже поставил)... иначе мне бы самому его писать пришлось XD XD XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот тебе база на основе которой ты можешь сам написать конечный код

```
public void Update(){
    JumpLogic();
}

public void JumpLogic {
    // выходим из логики прыжка если мы не на земле
    if (!onGround)
        return;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
         // запоминаем текущее время как нажатой клавиши
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
         // запоминаем текущее время как отжатой клавиши
         // можно сохранять локально в методе
    }

    if ( ) //если промежуток времени больше секунды
    {    
        //Большой прыжок
        br.AddForce(jumpImpulse * jumpHeightLong);
    
        // логика обнуления временного промежутка
    } else { //Если меньше секунды
        //Малый прыжок
        br.AddForce(jumpImpulse * jumpHeight);
    
        // логика обнуления временного промежутка
    }
}
```

Если нужна не ступенчатая зависимость а линейная, можно взять некий делитель от прошедшего времени умноженный на стартовую скорость прыжка вместо последней иф конструкции. И ограничить максимальную силу прыжка дополнительным ифом.